# dplyr column selection with placeholder . and paste in mutate_at

Tags: r, select, dplyr, purrr

I would like to replace missing values with averages.

To do this, I use
mutate_at and since I have a long list of variables.

This is an example:

```
dat <- data.frame(A=c(1,3,NA), B=c(0,NA,1), A_mean=c(2,2,2), B_mean=c(0.5,0.5,0.5))
dat %>% mutate_at(.vars=c("A", "B"), list(~ case_when(is.na(.) ~ get(paste0(., "_mean")),
                                                          TRUE ~ .)))
```

I don't understand how to tell dplyr to select A_mean, B_mean etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can split the dataset with `split.default` on the substring of column names and then do the `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
dat %>%
      split.default(str_remove(names(.), "_.*"))  %>%
      map_dfc(~ .x %>% mutate(!! names(.)[1] := 
         case_when(is.na(!!rlang::sym(names(.)[1])) ~ 
       !! rlang::sym(names(.)[2]), TRUE ~ !!rlang::sym(names(.)[1])
            )))
# A A_mean   B B_mean
#1 1      2 0.0    0.5
#2 3      2 0.5    0.5
#3 2      2 1.0    0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(A = ifelse(is.na(A), coalesce(A_mean), A), 
         B = ifelse(is.na(B), coalesce(B_mean), B))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25744381)

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't really solve the problem because I would have to write it out for each variable. I would like to know whether there is a solution with placeholders.